# Add menu item to file explorer

Tags: blackberry

I need to add a menu item to the file explorer but need to be visible images and documents (text files,pdf,doc etc).

When I use below piece of code the menu item is getting added to all the folders when I open file explorer.

```
ApplicationDescriptor appDesc = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();

ApplicationMenuItemRepository amir = ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance(); 

amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_BROWSE, this,appDesc);
amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_ITEM, this,appDesc);
```

As per API we can specify the MIME type to make the menu item visible only to specific files.I used the below code but the menu item is visible only for images and not for document types.

```
ApplicationDescriptor appDesc = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();

ApplicationMenuItemRepository amir = ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance(); 

amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_BROWSE, this,appDesc,new String("image/*;text/*;application/*")); 
amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_ITEM, this,appDesc,new String("image/*;text/*;application/*"));
```

I also tried with the below code but still the menu item is visible only to images but not to document types.

```
ApplicationDescriptor appDesc = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();

ApplicationMenuItemRepository amir = ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance(); 

amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_BROWSE, this,appDesc,new String("image/*")); 
amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_ITEM, this,appDesc,new String("image/*"));  
amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_BROWSE, this,appDesc,new String("text/*")); 
amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_ITEM, this,appDesc,new String("text/*"));
```

Need help to achieve the requirement.

Comment: check the sample demo which is provided by Blackberry >V5.0. Then you may get an idea of how to implement;

Comment: i checked the samples given but did not find anything relevant can pls tell me the exact one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance().addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_BROWSE,new BrowserMenuItemClass(0),ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(),"image/jpeg" );    
    ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance().addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_ITEM,new BrowserMenuItemClass(0),ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(),"image/jpeg" );  
    ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance().addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_BROWSE,new BrowserMenuItemClass(0),ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(),"image/gif" ); 
    ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance().addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_FILE_EXPLORER_ITEM,new BrowserMenuItemClass(0),ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(),"image/gif" );
```